# Why is the WPA2-PSK key length limited to 63 characters?

Tags: key, wifi, wpa

I wonder why there is a limit of just **63** characters for the passphrase of WPA2-PSK. It's not even a power of two and looks very unusual to me, but surely there's some deeper meaning to this number.

Comment: The encryption key may be from 8 to 63 printable ASCII characters or 64 hexadecimal digits. The maximum length results in 256 bit strength, which is what 64 digits (8 bits each) multiplied by 4 bits/digit yields.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The PSK is derived from the passphrase using PBKDF2 key derivation function with SHA1 as the pseudo random function. The passphrase is an 8-63 character ASCII encoded string.

PSK = PBKDF2(PassPhrase, ssid, ssidLength, 4096, 256)

The PSK is 32 bytes (256 bits), often displayed as 64 hex characters.

According to the 802.11i specification:

> A pass-phrase is a sequence of between 8 and 63 ASCII-encoded characters. The limit of 63 comes
>   from the desire to distinguish between a pass-phrase and a PSK displayed as 64 hexadecimal
>   characters.

So the difference is just to distinguish a 64 hex character PSK from a 8-63 character ASCII passhprase.

Answer (score -3):

Looking around the web, it looks like WPA2 takes 64 characters. In any event, each character is 8 bits long which is an easy number to store. My educational guess is that they just needed a cutoff number.

Answer (score -4):

63 chars terminated with an 0-byte (which is quite usual while programming strings in microprocessors) makes a length of 64. And that's a number you're looking for: it is not only a power of 2, but also of 8 and 16.

Comment: I thought so before and did take as sluggish implementation quirk (the added 0)
But I just reread the IEEE 802.11-2012 for that point.

Comment: Did you mean multiple? `16*16` is 256, not 64.